# Disabling JavaScript in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I usually go to Chrome content settings.  I usually go there to enable / disbale js in chrome. Which is too many clicks. Is there a shortcut to enable/disable JavaScript or access content settings.

PS: enabling it back once it is disabled is easy, as a icon is added to the address bar but disabling is the main culprit

Comment: I think your method is the only way to do it, too many clicks or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple way is to

1. Open the console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Click the hamburger icon on the right
3. Go to "Settings"
4. Under "General" check "Disable JavaScript"

Comment: Thank you! Although, it has changed a bit now, you have to open the console by pressing `F12`, then open the settings menu by pressing `F1` or clicking the 3 dots and going to settings. Then the first option here is "Disable Javascript".

Answer (score 7):

Since Chrome 16, there is an extension named [Quick Javascript Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje) that turns Javascript on/off on the fly.

Comment: Do you know of a hotkey which works with this extension?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Chrome on Windows then you can create a copy of your Chrome shortcut (rename it to `Google Chrome no JS`, for example). Right-click on it and select `Properties`. Add `-disable-javascript` to the end of the `Target` field. The end result should look something like this:

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -disable-javascript

When you open Chrome using this shortcut then JavaScript is disabled

Answer (score 3):

About every configuration/preferences screen in Chrome is a web page, so you can add a link to this URL to your Bookmarks Bar:

```
chrome://settings/content
```

Comment: On my Chromium (v.51) it's just `chrome://settings/content` (I get redirected to this with a nice pop-up, Cookies, Images and JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

You could use an extension like [NotScripts](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/odjhifogjcknibkahlpidmdajjpkkcfn). From the plugin page:

> NotScripts gives you a high degree of "NoScript" like control over what javascript, iframes, and plugins runs in your browser to increase security and lower the CPU usage. It is useful to help mitigate some attacks like certain cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities and drive by downloads by blocking the third-party content before it even runs with it's default deny policy.